# Lockscreen Widget Doesn't Dissappear After Finish Playing Video

Tags: ios, avplayer, lockscreen, mpremotecommandcenter

I'm working on an app like Netflix, while the user watching a video, he can lock the screen and see the lock screen controller with the video content.

**ISSUE 1**

When the app goes back to foreground, the user exits the player, locks the screen again but the player controller is still in the lock screen.

**ISSUE 2**

After the user watches a video, exits the player and enters another video, when he locks the screen the player lock screen controller plays 2 video, the current one and the one from before.

From what I understand, because of the MPRemoteCommandCenter completion methods (playCommand, pauseCommand etc.) the player never dealocated from memory.

My custom player class setting the lock screen controller:

```
private var nowPlayingInfo : [String:Any] = [:]

//MARK: UPDATING LOCKSCREEN STATUS
func updateLockscreenInfo(playPosition: Double? = nil) {
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = currentItem?.duration.seconds ?? 0
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = playPosition ?? currentTime().seconds
    nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = rate
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
}

//MARK: LOCKSCREEN PLAYER DELEGATES
private func setupLockScreen() {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        print(self)
        //after playing 2 videos, prints twixe 2 different instances
        self?.play()
        self?.updateLockscreenInfo()
        return .success
    }
}
//MARK: LOCK SCREEN INITIAL SETTER ( IMAGE & TITLE )
private func setControllerLockScreen(imageURL: String?, title: String?) {
    
    nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = title
    
    if let imageURL = imageURL, let url = URL(string: imageURL) {
        var data : Data?
        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
                    return image
                })
            }
        }
        catch {
            po(name: "error downloading image: ", data: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
}
```

When I remove 'commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget', the lock screen doesn't even show.

Answer (score 0):

```
// store handler
var handler: Any?

handler = commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
    return .success
}

// remove handler when you close the video
handler.map(commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget)
```